# Android- use device (google) account mail for automatic registring

Tags: android, get, registration, account

In my app there is Register activity which shows on first start.
I want that users don't have to type their mail and/or username. I want to get their mail and/or name and send it to my server application for registering there.
How can I get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) for that you get all accounts of google.

```
public String getAccountsName(){
     AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this); 
     Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google"); 
     List<String> possibleEmails = new LinkedList<String>();

     for (Account account : accounts) {
       // TODO: Check possibleEmail against an email regex or treat
       // account.name as an email address only for certain account.type values.
       possibleEmails.add(account.name);
     }

     if(!possibleEmails.isEmpty() && possibleEmails.get(0) != null){
         String email = possibleEmails.get(0);
         String[] parts = email.split("@");
         if(parts.length > 0 && parts[0] != null)
             return parts[0];
         else
             return null;
     }else
         return null;
 }
```